# unable to move/delete emails but CAN copy it

Tags: python, imaplib

I can copy email to another folder but unable to delete it from INBOX (Office 365)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import email, imaplib
user = 'user@example.com'
pwd = 'pass'

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
conn.login(user,pwd)
conn.select("Inbox")

resp, items = conn.uid("search",None, 'All')
items = items[0].split()
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
    if resp == 'OK':
        email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
        if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
            continue
        if mail["Subject"].find("Linux") > 0:
            result = conn.uid('COPY', emailid, "Archive")
            print result
            if result[0] == 'OK':
             result = mov, data = conn.uid('STORE', emailid, '+FLAGS', 'Deleted Items')
             print result
             conn.expunge()
```

I'm getting below:

```
('OK', ['16 (FLAGS (\\Seen))'])
```

and emails stay in Inbox

Comment: What happens when you try to delete (EXPUNGE) an email? Mind that MOVE might be simply not in the capabilities of the system.

Comment: solved it, and posted as answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: had to add `\` in front of Deleted Items, i didn't add it at first because sample code was for Gmail 
So first copy emails to desired folder and then delete it from Inbox:

```
if mail["Subject"].find("Linux") > 0:
            result = conn.uid('COPY', emailid, "Archive")
            print result
            if result[0] == 'OK':
             result = mov, data = conn.uid('STORE',emailid, '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted Items)')
```

Comment: The flag you want is “\Deleted”, it is not a folder name.  You are adding two flags: \Deleted, and Items.